# On screen notifications for Samsung s4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy Gt 19505. I am currently running andriod 4.4.2
I was wondering if there's any way to get on screen notifications for messages etc whilst using other apps. 
I used to have an iPhone,  but switched to Samsung because of how customisable Android is. However, the onscreen notifications are something I'm greatly missing. 
I am aware of message previews in the lock screen, and have that enabled, but I would absolutely love to have in screen notifications whilst using other apps. I am willing to download other apps to be able to do this. 
Please please please help
Thank you

Comment: There are things like "heads-on notifications", which might fit what you describe. Please take a look at e.g. [Floatify Heads-up Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.floatify) if that might fit (you should be able to tell by its screenshots). More stuff to personalize notifications [can be found here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543).

Comment: [benjamin1994](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/116677/benjamin1994) can't comment but wants to say: *"maybe you want to check this link out and see if there is any Application available which suits your needs [Make Notifications interesting](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2014/04/19/11-android-apps-make-notifications-interesting/)"*.

Answer (score 0):

I really like ["HeadsUp" from Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.achep.headsup) and I use it myself.